# Отправка запроса по клику на кнопки без перехода

Tags: javascript, запрос

Такая задача: есть несколько кнопок с ссылками, клик по которым должен отправлять запрос по url, но перехода не должно быть и желательно перегрузки страницы.

Делал так:

```
<a class="command-btn" id="id_1" href="http://link_1"></a>
<a class="command-btn" id="id_2" href="http://link_2"></a>
```

и т.д.

Скрипт:

```
var commandBTN = $('.command-btn').attr('href')    
$('.command-btn').click(function() {
     $.get(commandBTN);
     return false;
     commandBTN = null;
});
```

Comment: просто отправлять запрос по ссылке? и больше ничего не должно происходить? там подгрузка данных и т.д. и т.п.?

Comment: Да, просто отправить запрос, без ответа. Сделать так, как будто ты перешил на ссылку в фоне (если так можно объяснить).

Comment: Странно у вас после return false стоит commandBTN = null;

Comment: Я понимаю, что это не правильно. Я с той целью, чтобы очищать переменную, которая получает значение HREF. Но она всё равно берет самы первый HREF. А мне нужно, чтобы каждый раз брался HREF с конкретной кнопки

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вернуть `false` из `click` должно быть достаточно чтобы предотвратить переход, а запрос делаете уже руками:

```js
$('.command-btn').click(function() {
  console.log('click');

  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get(link, function(r) {
    console.log(r);
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="command-btn" id="id_1" href="https://httpbin.org/ip">LINK 1</a>
  <a class="command-btn" id="id_2" href="https://httpbin.org/user-agent">LINK 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Я так пробовал, но не вижу чтобы летел GET. Спасибо, проверю. Мне нужно чтобы оборудование реагировало на переход по ссылке

Comment: Откройте консоль браузера, пример рабочий.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Так всё работает.